# Connecting to Tor Directory Authority via Proxy Server (Protocol Question)

Tags: proxy, directory, https

I've been trying to connect to the Tor Network from home, but my country's ISP has blocked all of the Tor Directory Authorities' IPs. No luck reaching them so far. I know, there are bridges, but seems like they are blocking them too, since I've got a bridge via email, yet still wasn't able to connect.

I know of one thing still, which is unblockable: proxy servers. There is just too many of them, so they cannot block them.

I've gathered some proxy servers and now I'm trying to connect to the Directory Authority through them. One thing I don't know: what protocol of messaging is used, when connecting to them?

1. I connect to the proxy. Now all HTTP traffic I send to them is relayed to a target host.
2. Through the proxy I send an HTTP `CONNECT` request to Directory Authority's `IP:PORT`. Looks like this: `CONNECT 154.35.175.225:80 HTTP/1.1\r\n` (this is `IP:PORT` of **Faravahar**).
3. In response I get an empty response.

Is it right? Is the protocol I'm trying to use applicable to the host? How can I receive the information needed to create a circuit? Or maybe I'm mistaken that I need to connect to the Directory Authority?

Comment: What is your goal? To access tor Tor network as a regular user? Or do you specifically want to download something from a directory authority?

Comment: @Steve I would like to access the Tor network as a regular user, but ISP in my country blocks authority relays, so TOR network is inaccessible. They block some of the bridges, too. And I have to do this from within C# code, so that's why I'm asking the first question I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tor processes (client proxies, relays, bridges, etc) do not communicate over HTTP. They use a custom link protocol within a TLS connection. You *must* use a tor proxy (or generally, a proxy that speaks Tor's protocol) to access the network. If you really wanted to use an HTTP proxy, you could try using the [`HTTPSProxy` torrc option](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#HTTPSProxy), which routes all of the tor proxy's connections through this HTTP proxy. This requires an HTTP proxy that supports [HTTP CONNECT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/CONNECT).

---

The IP address `154.35.175.225` is not the address of gabelmoo; you're trying to connect to a different relay (Faravahar).

Most relays and authorities have a [directory port](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt) enabled, which allows you to download directory documents over HTTP. For example, you can download [gabelmoo](https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#details/F2044413DAC2E02E3D6BCF4735A19BCA1DE97281)'s server descriptor using:

```
curl 131.188.40.189/tor/server/authority
```

But you cannot use this port to access the Tor network as a client.